# AoPS 2015-2016 Mock AMC #21, by AlcumusGuy

Tags: contest-math

I was doing a Mock AMC 10 (title) from AoPS (also title).
I got really confused on number 21 because solution was bad.

Here it is:

A positive integer $n$ is called expoprime if for every prime $p$ dividing $n$, there exists a prime number $q$ such that $n$ is divisible by $p^q$ but not by $p^{q+1}$. Denote by the function $S(N)$ the sum of all divisors of $N$ that are expoprime. What is $S(2025) - S(2016)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you send the link to that mock? Is it on AoPS Mock Contests (I am an active AoPS user to - in fact, I am one of your friends on AoPS)?

Comment: What's the answer? Somewhere around 2500?